# Intermittent JVM crash under load

Tags: jboss5.x, jvm-crash

I am currently load testing my clustered application which is running in JBoss 5.1, with JDK 1.6.0_45 and I am experiencing intermittent JVM crashes. From the error report (further details from report below) it appears that the eden space is full (100%) at the time of the crash, so I suspect that this is the most likely candidate.

I have therefore been running JVisualVM to look for memory leaks, specifically monitoring my own classes. I can see these classes growing in memory, but then they are periodically cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Even if there was a memory leak, I would have expected to see OutOfMemory errors before a complete JVM crash anyway. Can anyone help to point me in the right direction with where the problem may lie? Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006dba43f7, pid=3980, tid=2556
#
# JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x2c43f7]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

snip

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 670272K, used 662831K [0x00000007d5560000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 641728K, 100% used [0x00000007d5560000,0x00000007fc810000,0x00000007fc810000)
  from space 28544K, 73% used [0x00000007fc810000,0x00000007fdcabf68,0x00000007fe3f0000)
  to   space 28352K, 12% used [0x00000007fe450000,0x00000007fe7d0e60,0x0000000800000000)
 PSOldGen        total 1398144K, used 1096904K [0x0000000780000000, 0x00000007d5560000, 0x00000007d5560000)
  object space 1398144K, 78% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007c2f32250,0x00000007d5560000)
 PSPermGen       total 422848K, used 378606K [0x0000000760000000, 0x0000000779cf0000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 422848K, 89% used [0x0000000760000000,0x00000007771bb800,0x0000000779cf0000)
```

snip

```
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Dhttp.proxyHost=testproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8010 -Dhttps.proxyHost=testproxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8010 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=testkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=testkeystore -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.mydomain.com -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=900000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=900000 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Djava.library.path=C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\native;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\lib\endorsed 
java_command: org.jboss.Main -c hops-cnf -b 0.0.0.0
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

Comment: A JVM crash is rarely a code issue - You've probably run into a bug in the implementation of the JVM.

From the report, it looks like the GC is trying to run, but it crashes the VM for some reason. Some things to try are:

 - Run on a 64-bit JVM with -Xmx4G?
 - Can you try not using the -Xms2G? If you set the Xms and Xmx flags to the same value, the heap has no space to grow. You can try without the Xms and Xmx flags too

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with the JVM version and the eden space. Your best bet is probably to reduce the GC threading? Try with

```
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=5m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```